# getting the delta between two separate queries

Tags: python, sql

Query 1

```
Select *
from tableA ta
left join tableB tb on tb.value1=ta.value1
where value1 is like '%something%'
```

generates this table

```
value1 value2
a      1
b      2
c      3
d      4
```

Query 2

```
Select *
from tableC tc
inner join tableD td on tc.value3=td.value4
where value3 is like '%something%else%'
```

generates table

```
value3 value4
a      1
b      2
e      5
f      6
```

how would I go about getting the 'delta' between the table from query 1 and query 2 (with respect to query 1)? i.e. how do I write my query such that I will get the result

```
value1 value2
c      3
d      4
```

the two queries I have are both pretty complicated, so I've abandoned trying to use *where value is not like '%%'*. I think the best way is to create temporary tables or use python to string match, but I don't know how to do either of those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `LEFT JOIN` and look for the null values (i.e. such that don't appear on the second table):

```
select A.value1, A.value2 from 
(Select *
from tableA ta
left join tableB tb on tb.value1=ta.value1
where value1 is like '%something%') as A 
LEFT JOIN 
(Select *
from tableC tc
inner join tableD td on tc.value3=td.value4
where value3 is like '%something%else%') as B
ON A.value1 = B.value3 and A.value2 = B.value4 
WHERE B.value3 is null and B.value4 is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
Select *
from tableA ta
left join tableB tb on tb.value1=ta.value1
where value1 is like '%something%'
EXCEPT
Select *
from tableC tc
inner join tableD td on tc.value3=td.value4
where value3 is like '%something%else%'
```

More on this [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html)